# What would be the best way to get data from a parent in order to achieve this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

https://jsfiddle.net/cshLevtz/

```
$('.items li .actions .btn').click(function() {
    alert(
        $(this).data('action') + 
        $(this).parent().parent().data('id')
    );
});
```

I currently have this however using `.parent().parent()` feels really hacky and like something that would easily break if I decide to add more to the html so I was wondering, is there a better way to get the `data-id` of the `li`?

**Edit:** based on the answers it seems like it boils down to either `.parents('li')` or `.closest('li')`, I'm not entirely sure which one would be more fitting.

Comment: You could use `.closest('li')`

Comment: you can use this `$(this).parents("li").data('id')`

Answer (score 0):

`parent` can take parameter [`selector`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) .

```
selector
Type: Selector
A string containing a selector expression to match elements against.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use either

```
parents('li')
```

or

```
closest('li')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.parents()` with parameter `li`

```
$(".items li .actions .btn").click(function() {
    alert(
        $(this).data("action") + 
        $(this).parents("li").data("id")
    );
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cshLevtz/1/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.items li .actions .btn').click(function() {
    alert( $(this).data('action') + $(this).parents("li").data('id') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="items">
    <li data-id="1">
        <div class="contents">
            <p>First Content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-action="edit">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-action="delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li data-id="2">
        <div class="contents">
            <p>Second Content</p>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-action="edit">Edit</a>
            <a href="#" class="btn" data-action="delete">Delete</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```